# SSRS - Trying to force two tablixes to align with charts and hidden columns

Tags: reporting-services, charts, width, vertical-alignment, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to build a "quadrant" report, where there are four aligned, equal-sized tablixes (tablices?) on a page. Here's the issue I'm running into on the two quadrants that should be on the left side of the page:

The "top" tablix starts with a basic table, with the caveat that columns that sum to 0 are hidden. Below the table is a row with two pie charts, and each pie chart should be the size of roughly 2-4 of the table columns.

The "bottom" tablix has two side-by-side basic tables, each followed by side-by-side bar charts.

The problem is that they want the two tablixes to exactly align vertically. That is, they want both the left and right edges of the two tablixes perfectly aligned. But with the top tablix, columns sometimes show and sometimes don't, and when the pie charts span multiple columns including one or more that are hidden, SSRS likes to force one column to expand to the full width of the chart which is not what I want. This happens even if I have the top tablix having exactly 2N columns, where N is the number of actual data columns, and then any one of the data columns that is hidden has a "mirror universe" blank column that shows to try to fix the number of columns.

I am too new to post pictures, but I believe I'm able to link to a mock-up I made:

[Link to mock-up of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hPv9.png)

Comment: My workaround was to remove the pie charts and the footer from the top tablix, set every single remaining cell in that tablix to False for both CanGrow and CanShrink, and add a rectangle below the tablix with the pie charts and the footer. I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution but this did solve my problem for now.

Comment: How about hiding the data of the columns that you don't want to show? Just use your hidden expression for the text box value headers and expression - i.e. `=IIF(SUM(Fields!CANADA_SALES.value) = 0, NOTHING, "Canada Sales")` for the header and `=IIF(SUM(Fields!CANADA_SALES.value) = 0, NOTHING, SUM(Fields!CANADA_SALES.value))` for the data

Comment: @HannoverFist Yup, that was the "mirror universe" columns I mentioned in the post. The weird thing I had to figure out is that to make the two quadrants line up, I had to actually move part of the right quadrant into the left quadrant. [Screenshot.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/pFvBRxwYofuqxV8V7) Looks weird in VS, but appears perfectly in the deployed report.